# Can you add to a CountVectorizer in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

I'd like to create a CountVectorizer in [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) based on a corpus of text and then add more text to the CountVectorizer later (adding to the original dictionary).

If I use `transform()`, it does maintain the original vocabulary, but adds no new words.  If I use `fit_transform()`, it just regenerates the vocabulary from scratch.  See below:

```
In [2]: count_vect = CountVectorizer()

In [3]: count_vect.fit_transform(["This is a test"])
Out[3]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [4]: count_vect.vocabulary_  
Out[4]: {u'is': 0, u'test': 1, u'this': 2}

In [5]: count_vect.transform(["This not is a test"])
Out[5]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [6]: count_vect.vocabulary_
Out[6]: {u'is': 0, u'test': 1, u'this': 2}

In [7]: count_vect.fit_transform(["This not is a test"])
Out[7]: 
<1x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [8]: count_vect.vocabulary_
Out[8]: {u'is': 0, u'not': 1, u'test': 2, u'this': 3}
```

I'd like the equivalent of an `update()` function.  I'd like it to work something like this:

```
In [2]: count_vect = CountVectorizer()

In [3]: count_vect.fit_transform(["This is a test"])
Out[3]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [4]: count_vect.vocabulary_  
Out[4]: {u'is': 0, u'test': 1, u'this': 2}

In [5]: count_vect.update(["This not is a test"])
Out[5]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [6]: count_vect.vocabulary_
Out[6]: {u'is': 0, u'not': 1, u'test': 2, u'this': 3}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithms implemented in `scikit-learn` are designed to be fit on all the data at once, which is necessary for most ML algorithms (though interesting not the application that you describe), so there is no `update` functionality.

There is a way to get to what you want by thinking of it slightly differently though, see the following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
count_vect.fit_transform(["This is a test"])
print count_vect.vocabulary_
count_vect.fit_transform(["This is a test", "This is not a test"])
print count_vect.vocabulary_
```

Which outputs

```
{u'this': 2, u'test': 1, u'is': 0}
{u'this': 3, u'test': 2, u'is': 0, u'not': 1}
```